# Maximal Bipartite Matching

Tags: c#

I have been working on creating a code solution for the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://www.hungarianalgorithm.com/index.php), and from the testing, the slowest and buggiest part has been the bipartite matching.  The most recent rendition is based on this [GeeksforGeeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/), but, I removed the recursion since that was a stack-overflow waiting to happen for my intended use.

```
public static class MaximumMatchingAlgorithm
{
    private const int Invalid = -1;

    public static IEnumerable<BipartiteMatch> Solve<TValue>(TValue[,] values, Func<TValue, bool> interpreter)
    {
        var m = values.GetLength(0);
        var n = values.GetLength(1);

        var mappings = new Queue<int>[m];
        var matches = new int[n];

        for (var index = 0; index < n; index++)
        {
            matches[index] = Invalid;
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < m; x++)
        {
            var mapping = mappings[x] = new Queue<int>(n);

            for (var y = 0; y < n; y++)
            {
                if (interpreter(values[x, y]))
                {
                    mapping.Enqueue(y);
                }
            }

            var currentX = x;

            while (mapping.TryDequeue(out var y))
            {
                var tempX = matches[y];
                var otherMapping = tempX != Invalid ? mappings[tempX] : null;

                if (otherMapping == null)
                {
                    matches[y] = currentX;
                    break;
                }

                if (otherMapping.Count == 0) continue;

                matches[y] = currentX;
                currentX = tempX;
                mapping = otherMapping;
            }
        }

        for (var index = 0; index < n; index++)
        {
            yield return new BipartiteMatch(matches[index], index);
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any glaring issues with how I converted the code, or are there any optimizations that could/should be made?

**UPDATE:** After more testing, I found a test case where this algorithm produced an incorrect result.  I switched the `Queue` to a `Stack`, which is what it should have been in the first place in order to replicate recursion.